# Python script ot convert peptide sequence in SVM input format

Tags: python, sequence

I have one query related to conversion of protein sequence into the SVM input format. Recently i found one tutorial which shows the conversion of protein sequence into sparse binary representation  (Ex. Given below)kindly please help me, like how can i convert my 7mer sequences into this format with the help of python script.

```
Amino Acide                Binary code 
A                   10000000000000000000
C                   01000000000000000000
D                   00100000000000000000
E                   00010000000000000000
F                   00001000000000000000
G                   00000100000000000000
H                   00000010000000000000
I                   00000001000000000000
K                   00000000100000000000
L                   00000000010000000000
M                   00000000001000000000
N                   00000000000100000000
P                   00000000000010000000
Q                   00000000000001000000
R                   00000000000000100000
S                   00000000000000010000
T                   00000000000000001000
V                   00000000000000000100
W                   00000000000000000010
Y                   00000000000000000001
```

Example with 2mer peptide

```
Peptide            Sparse binary encoding of peptide        SVM input

AD            1000000000000000000000100000000000000000    +1 1:1 23:1
YC            0000000000000000000101000000000000000000    -1 20:1 22:1
```

It should generate a out.txt file of SVM input for a respective peptide. like given below.

```
+1 1:1 23:1
-1 20:1 22:1
```

Thanks.

Comment: What is your input? A peptide string ("AGCD") or the binary code. And what are the rules to construct this "SVM input"?

Comment: Insight into how the calculation happens would be very useful.

Comment: My input is 600 7mer to 9mer Peptide  sequences which should be converted into Sparse binary encoding to prepare training set.

Answer (score 1):

```
bin_dict = {
'A':'10000000000000000000',
'C':'01000000000000000000',
'D':'01000000000000000000',
'E':'00010000000000000000',
'F':'00001000000000000000',
'G':'00000100000000000000',
'H':'00000010000000000000',
'I':'00000001000000000000',
'K':'00000000100000000000',
'L':'00000000010000000000',
'M':'00000000001000000000',
'N':'00000000000100000000',
'P':'00000000000010000000',
'Q':'00000000000001000000',
'R':'00000000000000100000',
'S':'00000000000000010000',
'T':'00000000000000001000',
'V':'00000000000000000100',
'W':'00000000000000000010',
'Y':'00000000000000000001'
}

seq="ACDE"
bin_string=''
svm_string=''
for letter in seq:
    bin_string+=bin_dict[letter]
```

This will generate string with binary representation of  the seq.

Comment: in SVM we generally use two type of data set positive and negative, so for example if i have 10 postive data and 10 negative data so i have to  use positive and negative sine respectively.for example in above example AD represents the Positive one while YC is negative data set so we have used respective sines.

Comment: how do you know which data set is positive and which negative? also do you need the SVM data written in pairs?

Comment: I know the positive and negative data set because i have extracted these data from the DATA bases and stored in separate files but to classify these data i need to keep its output in a single txt file with the positive and negative sine to generate a SVM model.It will help SVM classifier to enumerate a suitalbe model for these purpose

Comment: I changed my answer to generate binary representation strings, since I still don't 100% understand what exactly you want to do

Comment: If you really feel to solve this query kindly provide me your mail ID i will send you the detailed explanation which i have write  to post here but unfortunately charectore limitation of this blog stopping me to doing this. Otherwise thanks for you kind support.

Comment: ullrich.janice@objectmail.com